# Regex in drool file

Tags: drools

I am using regex in drool for validating the password.

```
    rule "Reset Password"
when
    $event : IIPEvent ( name == 'save')
    $vm : Login(userProfile != null)
then
    
    if($vm.getPassword().getValue() != null && $vm.getPassword().getValue().matches('^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$'))
    outcome.addFieldError('password', 'Password minimum eight characters, at least one letter and one number', $vm, false);
            
end
```

When I deploy this in Tomcat server, I am getting following exception

line 11:104 no viable alternative at character 'd'
line 11:113 no viable alternative at character '\'
Oct 23, 2020 8:48:21 PM org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule buildKnowledgePackages
SEVERE: Unable to build KieBaseModel:defaultKieBase
Unable to determine the used declarations.
java.lang.NullPointerException : [Rule name='Reset Password']
java.lang.NullPointerException

If any one know that how to resolve it, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing your matching on the left hand side, not the right hand side. That's what the 'matches' operator is for.

```
rule "Reset Password"
when
    exists(IIPEvent(name == "save"))
    $vm : Login( userProfile != null,
                 password != null,
                 password matches "(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{8,}$")
then
  outcome.addFieldError("password", "Password minimum eight characters, at least one letter and one number", $vm, false);
end
```

As to why you were getting the error -- you have `\d` instead of `\\d`. You need to escape the backslash for character classes within strings. You can tell this is the issue from the error messages: `no viable alternative at character 'd'` and then `no viable alternative at character '\'`.